# Strange behavior in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

this open the view page with tons of errors (can't read the front-end=css/js codes)

```
Route::get('category/{cat}' , function($cat) {
   return view('main/category');
});
```

as you see

[image]

however this opens it without any problem

```
Route::get('category' , function() {
   return view('main/category');
});
```

how to implement this route parameters ?

example of my linking implementation

in master.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
```

in public folder -> css/responsive.css

Comment: What are the errors? How are you linking to the JS and CSS assets into your layout?

Comment: @fubar - I updated the question , can you take a look ?

Comment: Please post the relevant code from your layout showing how you link to your JS and CSS.

Comment: I link it normally : 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assets are not linking correctly for the `/category/{cat}` URL, because you're using a relative path.

Therefore, when you navigate to a route that isn't the root of your site, the subdirectory is essentially prepended to the path. E.g.

```
category/css/responsive.css
```

To fix this, you should use one of the Laravel URL helpers. This will then output your asset paths with an absolute URL. E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/responsive.css') }}" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `artisan serve`, so don't use root folder name it url.

```
     /js/file.js
     /css/file.css
     /images/file.png
```

So that it would be like `http://localhost:8000/js/file.js` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/file.js`

And in route

```
  Route::get('category/{cat}' , function($cat) {
      return view('main.category');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use asset function:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/responsive.css') }}" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: do you know how to write PHP code inside a blade template - as I want to pick a random element from array ?